# How to send emails in android studio

Tags: android

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("message/rfc822");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"kaushikasameera@gmail.com"});
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(StaffHome.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

i try to do sending mails with this.
but a popup message says "No app can perform this task"

Comment: do you have an emailing application on the device?

Comment: You are running app in device or emulator?

Comment: try this i.setType("plain/text");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main cause of this issue is that there is no Application installed on device who can handle that intent.

if you want to test it you should have atleast one application.

If you want to make your own Email App then in MAnifest please insert IntentFilter

```
  <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is no email app available on the device you are testing.

most probably you are trying this on emulator. I suggest you to try it on a real device if that is the case.